# Getting "Element type is invalid" error while doing SSR with express and react

Tags: reactjs, express, babeljs, create-react-app, server-side-rendering

This is the error I am getting while doing SSR with express and node

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
> at renderElement (C:\Users\Uzair Khan\Documents\ssr-react\ssr-react\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6047:9)
> at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (C:\Users\Uzair Khan\Documents\ssr-react\ssr-react\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6108:11)
> at renderNodeDestructive (C:\Users\Uzair Khan\Documents\ssr-react\ssr-react\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6080:14)
> at retryTask (C:\Users\Uzair Khan\Documents\ssr-react\ssr-react\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6532:5)
> at performWork (C:\Users\Uzair Khan\Documents\ssr-react\ssr-react\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6580:7)
> at C:\Users\Uzair Khan\Documents\ssr-react\ssr-react\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6904:12
> at scheduleWork (C:\Users\Uzair Khan\Documents\ssr-react\ssr-react\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:78:3)
> at startWork (C:\Users\Uzair Khan\Documents\ssr-react\ssr-react\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6903:3)
> at renderToStringImpl (C:\Users\Uzair Khan\Documents\ssr-react\ssr-react\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:6977:3)
> at renderToString (C:\Users\Uzair Khan\Documents\ssr-react\ssr-react\node_modules\react-dom\cjs\react-dom-server-legacy.node.development.js:7065:10)
> at C:\Users\Uzair Khan\Documents\ssr-react\ssr-react/server.js:15:34
> at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Uzair Khan\Documents\ssr-react\ssr-react\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
> at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Uzair Khan\Documents\ssr-react\ssr-react\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:328:13)
> at C:\Users\Uzair Khan\Documents\ssr-react\ssr-react\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:286:9
> at param (C:\Users\Uzair Khan\Documents\ssr-react\ssr-react\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:365:14)
> at param (C:\Users\Uzair Khan\Documents\ssr-react\ssr-react\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:376:14)
> at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Uzair Khan\Documents\ssr-react\ssr-react\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:421:3)
> at next (C:\Users\Uzair Khan\Documents\ssr-react\ssr-react\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
> at SendStream.error (C:\Users\Uzair Khan\Documents\ssr-react\ssr-react\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:121:7)
> at SendStream.emit (node:events:526:28)
> at SendStream.emit (node:domain:475:12)
> at SendStream.error (C:\Users\Uzair Khan\Documents\ssr-react\ssr-react\node_modules\send\index.js:270:17)
> at SendStream.redirect (C:\Users\Uzair Khan\Documents\ssr-react\ssr-react\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:185:12)
> at SendStream.emit (node:events:526:28)
> at SendStream.emit (node:domain:475:12)
> at SendStream.redirect (C:\Users\Uzair Khan\Documents\ssr-react\ssr-react\node_modules\send\index.js:475:10)
> at onstat (C:\Users\Uzair Khan\Documents\ssr-react\ssr-react\node_modules\send\index.js:723:41)
> at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (node:fs:199:5)

This is my first time doing SSR and I am stuck due to this error. I have tried multiple techniques but not understanding why I am getting this error
This is my server.js file

```
import React from "react";
import express from "express";
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";
import { StaticRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import App from "./src/App";
import path from "path";
import fs from "fs";

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("./build", { index: false }));

app.use("/*", (req, res) => {
  const reactApp = renderToString(
    <StaticRouter location={req.url}>
      <App />
    </StaticRouter>
  );

  const templateFile = path.resolve("./build/index.html");

  fs.readFile(templateFile, "utf8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(500).send("Not working");
    }

    return res.send(
      data.replace('<div id="root"></div>', `<div id="root">${reactApp}</div>`)
    );
  });
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log("server is listening on port 8080");
});
```

and this is my index.js file of react

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App.js";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.hydrate(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
reportWebVitals();
```

and lastly this is my App.js file

```
import React from "react";
import { Routes, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import About from "./pages/About";
import Articles from "./pages/Articles";
function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Server side rendering tutorial</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/about">About</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to="/articles">Articles</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="/articles" element={<Articles />} />
      </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This error appears as soon I tried to handle routing and also I am using CRA
Please tell me how to resolve this error and also recommend me some online platforms where I can learn in detail about react SSR with express